# react ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

From my parent react component's render method I am creating a list of child radio button components.

I need to call a method once the render is completed, i.e., children components are also rendered completely.

I tried following mechanism:

1. passed a callback: It didn't worked. It was called before rendering.
2. called the method directly in componentDidMount. Same issue
3. called the method in componentDidUpdate. Same issue

I am passing all the data through props to parent -> child and there is no redux involved.

How I can achieve this ?

Comment: Please show the code you have written. You probably don't need cDM/cDU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply wrap in a timeout in the parent component's `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
   setTimeout(this.myMethod, 1000/60)
}
```

`componentDidUpdate` is not invoked on the initial render, hence you cannot use it.

Comment: Didn't worked. I did following componentDidMount() {
   setTimeout(this.myMethod, 2000)
}

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It didn't initially as i was directly calling my method and I just changed it to an anonymous call and it worked.